# Is is possible to build containers using Dockerfile and an external file for environement variables?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a simple Dockerfile that I use to build a docker image using the command line.
I need to load environment variables from an external file instead to write them in the same Dockerfile. Is it possible? I'm aware that using docker composer you could use an env-file parameter but I don't use docker composer.

**Build command**

```
sudo docker build -t some/image -f Dockerfile .
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM golang:alpine
RUN mkdir -p /app
WORKDIR /app
ADD main /app/
ENV X="Y"
RUN ["chmod", "+x", "/app/main"]
ENTRYPOINT ["/app/main"]
EXPOSE 80 443 8080
```

Comment: Just like you can use an environment file with `docker-compose`, you can pass an environment file to `docker run` using the `--env-file` option. In both cases this is a *runtime* configuration, rather than part of the image build process.

Comment: And if you prefer to set variables at build time you can add them to the docker build command, although I have not seen a file option there - https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#set-build-time-variables---build-arg

Answer (score 0):

You can use the new flag named "--secret".

> It allows to mount secrets to build your image. those secrets are deletes after each layer writing.

However it works with buildkit only.

Here is a small example :

- Dockerfile

  ```
  RUN --mount=type=secret,id=mysecret \
    MYSECRET=$(cat /run/secrets/mysecret) \
    && export MYSECRET \
    && <do something with $MYSECRET env variable>
  ```
- Build command

  ```sh
  DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build --secret id=mysecret,src=docker/mysecret.txt .
  ```

And here is the official documentation :

https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/build_enhancements/#new-docker-build-secret-information